# charting in c# using asp.net

Tags: c#, timeline, charts, timelinemarkers

Can we design a point chart with y axis values say xyz,abc etc and x axis with dates.
This means xyz may be in 28/11/2012 but the actual x axis values would be fixed with say one month interval.

The point should be mapped on the proper spot.

If we can design this, then please let me know how.

Comment: What charting library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use standard values for the `Points` and add the date as `AxisLabel`

```
public Series CreateSeries(Dictionary<DateTime, double> values)
{
    var series = new Series();

    //Our x Value   
    var x = 0;
    //Loop through our values-Collection ordered by the date
    foreach (var value in values.OrderBy(item => item.Key))
    {
        //Add a point using our dummy value
        series.Points.Add(
            new DataPoint(x, value.Value) 
            {
                //AxisLabel sets the X-Axis-Label - here: our datestring
                AxisLabel = item.Key.ToShortDateString() 
            });
        //increment our dummy
        x++;
    }

    return series;
}
```

Comment: Hi I am using mscharts library. Thanks for you reply. It really helped me :)